# Why does a logical not-operation on an expression with the value -2147483648 result in 1？

Tags: c++, c, gcc

I created an integer `my_int_min` and assigned the value `INT_MIN`,

```c
my_int_min = -my_int_min = INT_MIN = -INT_MIN =  -2147483648
```

should be valid. So, I predicted that the expression `!(-my_int_min & INT_MIN)` should have a value of 0, but the actual operation results in 1.

I found `!(-my_int_min&my_int_min)` equal to 0 and `(-my_int_min&INT_MIN)` equal to -2147483648. Why `!(-my_int_min & INT_MIN)` is not equal to 0? The code is as follows.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>

int main()
{
    int my_int_min = INT_MIN;
    printf("INT_MIN=%d\t my_int_min=%d\t -INT_MIN=%d\t -my_int_min=%d\n", INT_MIN, my_int_min, -INT_MIN, -my_int_min);
    printf("!(-INT_MIN&INT_MIN)=%d\t !(-my_int_min&INT_MIN)=%d\n", !(-INT_MIN&INT_MIN), !(-my_int_min&INT_MIN));
    printf("!(-INT_MIN&my_int_min)=%d\t !(-my_int_min&my_int_min)=%d\n", !(-INT_MIN&my_int_min), !(-my_int_min&my_int_min));
    printf("(-my_int_min&INT_MIN)=%d\t !(-my_int_min&INT_MIN)=%d\n", (-my_int_min&INT_MIN), !(-my_int_min&INT_MIN));

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
INT_MIN=-2147483648      my_int_min=-2147483648  -INT_MIN=-2147483648    -my_int_min=-2147483648
!(-INT_MIN&INT_MIN)=0    !(-my_int_min&INT_MIN)=1
!(-INT_MIN&my_int_min)=0         !(-my_int_min&my_int_min)=0
(-my_int_min&INT_MIN)=-2147483648        !(-my_int_min&INT_MIN)=1
```

Comment: `INT_MIN` is a macro, you can't assign to it.

Comment: `-INT_MIN` causes overflow on two's complement systems, because `INT_MAX == -(INT_MIN+1)`

Comment: What is `x = -x = y` supposed to mean? Is the intent `x = -(x = y)`?

Comment: Before anybody says overflow has undefined behavior, so the compiler is allowed to do anything, observe that declaring `my_int_min` with `volatile` would prevent the compiler from knowing that `-my_int_min` overflows, so it would be required to generate code that works for all values for which it does not overflow. Clang still produces 1 in this case. So it must be producing code that works correctly for all values from −2,147,483,647 to +2,147,483,647, inclusive, but that produces 1 for −2,147,483,648, which is interesting.

Comment: *Why does a logical not-operation on an expression with the value -2147483648 result in 1?*  Well, it doesn't.  The question should be phrased: "Why does a logical not-operation on an expression with undefined behavior result in 1?"  And the answer is:  **undefined behavior**.

Comment: @Eljay: That is not the answer.

Comment: @EricPostpischil • It does not result in 1 on my machine.

Comment: @Eljay: Yes, so? That is still not an answer on why it behaves the way it does for the OP, nor does saying it is undefined behavior provide the answer. Saying something is undefined behavior only means the C standard does not impose any requirements. It does not explain what did happen. Most things in the world happen for reasons outside of the C standard, and explaining them involves using things outside the C standard.

Comment: @EricPostpischil • it explains why "should have a value of 0" expectation is incorrect.

Comment: @Eljay: That still does not answer the question why OP got 1, which is asked in their title. Answers that say the behavior is undefined promote ignorance and are harmful to learning. They tell students not to learn how things work. Compilers have designs and reasons that go beyond the C standard. C implementations have designs and reasons that go beyond the C standard. Learning those and related things is important for debugging, for designing compilers and other things, for guarding against exploits or for taking advantage of bugs (e.g., as the NSA seeks to do). They should not be downplayed.

Comment: @tadman:  `x=-x=y=-y` just to show that the four variables have the same value.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looking at code generated by Apple Clang 11.0.0 with `-O3` for x86_64 with `my_int_min` qualified as `volatile` suggests that Clang is optimizing the code by testing the sign of `my_int_min`.

Were we evaluating `! (x & INT_MIN)`, rather than `! (-my_int_min & INT_MIN)`, the nominal unoptimized code for this might be to get the value of `x`, AND it with −2,147,483,648, and then test the result to determine whether to print a “0” or a “1”.

When we optimize this, there is no need to perform the AND. If `x` is positive or zero, its sign bit is zero, so `x & INT_MIN` is zero, and `!` changes that to one, so we print “1”. Similarly, if `x` is negative, its sign bit is one, `x & INT_MIN` is `INT_MIN`, and `!` changes that to zero, so we print “0”. To implement this, Clang generates a compare instruction and then a `setle` instruction that provides the desired 0 or 1; the AND is optimized away.

Now if we consider instead `! (-x & INT_MIN)`, this is reversed for all defined cases: If `x` is positive or zero, we print “0”. If `x` is negative, we print “1”. Looking at this more closely: In all of the defined cases where `x` is negative, −2,147,483,648 < `x` < 0, so 0 < `-x` < +2,147,483,648, so the sign bit of `-x` is zero in all defined cases for negative `x`, so `-x & INT_MIN` is zero, and `! (-x & INT_MIN)` is one.

There is only one undefined case: `x` is `INT_MIN`, so `-x` overflows. For this case, Clang does not care about the generated code, so all it needs is the code for the defined cases described above. If `x` is negative, we print “1”, as if `-INT_MIN` generated a positive number instead of wrapping and producing `INT_MIN`.

Here are the relevant instructions, with my comments:

```
    xorl    %esi, %esi     // Initialize %esi to zero.
    cmpl    $0, -4(%rbp)   // Compare, to test the sign bit of `my_int_min`.
    setle   %sil           // Update %esi to one if `my_int_min` is negative.
```

Without `volatile`, Clang replaces the above code with a constant zero. However, having seen how optimization relies on the sign of an operand without consideration for overflow, we can presume that various compilers may (or may not) do similar things in various circumstances.

Comment: Thank you very much, I checked the assembly code generated by GCC and it is indeed optimized out of `AND`. This has helped me a lot.